# Is WiFi drone control protocol standardized?

Tags: quadcopters, recommendations, software

I'm searching for an app to control a Zerotech Doby drone. The official app "DoFun" is no more available, but surprisingly it works with another Chinese app "FlightGo".

I wonder if the WiFi protocol used there is somehow well known, and if there are any better, preferably opensource apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one has answered this question in pretty much a day, I'm gonna spread my half-knowledge now :)

I have never heard of a standardized wifi drone control protocol. However, I wouldn't be surprised if both chinese manufacturers inofficially use the same protocol (be it because they have a contract or because they just copy from each other or because they use the same control chips). I encountered this with a lot of LED strips: Most of these strips can be controlled with the same IR remote - across brands and so on. Even though, IR and WiFi are vastly different things, I think this could be the case here as well.

As for using the same control chips, this is also often the case with toy RC cars (27 and 40MHz). Most of the time, you can just use your remote to control your friend's car. I discovered that in kindergarden ^^.